# Postgresql Index Only Scan Doesnt Properly Work On Group By

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-performance

I have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE summary
(
    id serial NOT NULL,
    user_id bigint NOT NULL,
    country character varying(5),
    product_id bigint NOT NULL,
    category_id bigint NOT NULL,
    text_id bigint NOT NULL,
    text character varying(255),
    product_type integer NOT NULL,
    event_name character varying(255),
    report_date date NOT NULL,
    currency character varying(5),
    revenue double precision,
    last_event_time timestamp
);
```

My table size is 1786 MB (except index). In here, I've created index like below:

```
CREATE INDEX "idx_as_type_usr_productId_eventTime"
    ON summary USING btree
    (product_type, user_id, product_id, last_event_time)
    INCLUDE(event_name);
```

And my simple query looks like below:

```
select 
   event_name, 
   max(last_event_time) 
from summary s 
where s.user_id = ? and s.product_id = ? and s.product_type = ? 
   and s.last_event_time > '2020-03-01' and s.last_event_time < '2020-03-25'
group by event_name;
```

When I explain it, it looks like;

```
HashAggregate  (cost=93.82..96.41 rows=259 width=25) (actual time=9187.533..9187.536 rows=10 loops=1)
  Group Key: event_name
  Buffers: shared hit=70898 read=10579 dirtied=22650
  I/O Timings: read=3876.367
  ->  Index Only Scan using "idx_as_type_usr_productId_eventTime" on summary s  (cost=0.56..92.36 rows=292 width=25) (actual time=0.485..9153.812 rows=87322 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((product_type = 2) AND (product_id = ?) AND (product_id = ?) AND (last_event_time > '2020-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (last_event_time < '2020-03-25 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
        Heap Fetches: 35967
        Buffers: shared hit=70898 read=10579 dirtied=22650
        I/O Timings: read=3876.367
Planning Time: 0.452 ms
Execution Time: 9187.583 ms
```

In here, everything looks fine. But when I execute it, it takes more than 10 seconds, sometime it takes more than 30 seconds.

1. In here, if I execute it without Group By, it returns so quickly like less than 2 seconds. What can be the effect of Group By? The select part is so little (like a 500 rows).
2. This table has insert/update operations with 30/per second. Can this be related with this indexing problem?

**Updated:**

Query Without - GroupBy:

```
select 
   event_name, 
   last_event_time 
from summary s 
where s.user_id = ? and s.product_id = ? and s.product_type = ? 
   and s.last_event_time > '2020-03-01' and s.last_event_time < '2020-03-25';
```

Explain Without - Group By:

```
Index Only Scan using "idx_as_type_usr_productId_eventTime" on summary s  (cost=0.56..92.36 rows=292 width=25) (actual time=0.023..79.138 rows=87305 loops=1)
  Index Cond: ((product_type = ?) AND (user_id = ?) AND (product_id = ?) AND (last_event_time > '2020-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (last_event_time < '2020-03-25 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
  Heap Fetches: 22949
  Buffers: shared hit=37780 read=12143 dirtied=15156
  I/O Timings: read=4418.930
Planning Time: 0.639 ms
Execution Time: 4625.213 ms
```

Comment: Please show the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS), and in text format.  JSON format is nice for machines to read, but we are not machines.  And better yet, turn track_io_timing on first if it is not already.  And please do the same with the query without the GROUP BY, since you asked about that one too.

Comment: The query does not match the plan. `(last_event_time > '2020-03-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (last_event_time < '2020-03-25 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"` is not in the query. Please present a consistent question. Always start by disclosing your version of Postgres. And what Jeff said about text format.

Comment: @jjanes and Erwin; Question was edited like you said.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems:

- PostgreSQL had to set *hint bits*, which dirty the pages and cause writes.
- PostgreSQL has to fetch table rows from disk to fetch their visibility.
- PostgreSQL has to scan 80000 pages to get 87000 rows, so the index must be totally bloated.

The first two can be taken care of by running

```
VACUUM summary;
```

which is always a good idea after a bulk load, and the bloat can be cured by

```
REINDEX INDEX "idx_as_type_usr_productId_eventTime";
```

Comment: Laurenz, thanks for your answer. I know that is related with DB-cache because I fetched them sequentially. Hence, I updated question again. At this time, I fetched them with time break 15 minutes between two queries.

Comment: And here my main question is not differences between group-by and non-group-by. My main question is; there are only 500 rows to scan and this scan is index-only-scan so why fetching time takes so long?

Comment: I have adapted the answer to the changed question.

Comment: But this table has at least 30 insert/update operations for per second. So should I do reindex it all time? Is it applicable solution?

Comment: That is the root cause of your problem. Tune autovacuum and use HOT updates. But that is material for another question.